# wrap nested dictionary with nested list values

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a python nested dictionary that I am trying to wrap each level of the dictionary in a list. Reason being is this dictionary is getting converted into a Java Script Object and I am trying to maintain the order of the dictionary. I have given an example of what I was attempting to do. Any help in doing this is greatly appreciated.

Input:

```
myDict = {
   'outerkey1': {'innerkey1': 1,
                 'innerkey2': 2,
                 'innerkey3': 3,
                 'innerkey4': 4,
                 'innerkey5': 5,
                 'innerkey6': 6,
                 'innerkey7': 7,
                 'innerkey8': 8,
                 'innerkey9': 9,
                 'innerkey10': 10,
                 'innerkey11': 11},
   'outerkey2': {'innerkey1': 100,
                 'innerkey2': 200,
                 'innerkey3': 300,
                 'innerkey4': 400,
                 'innerkey5': 500,
                 'innerkey6': 600,
                 'innerkey7': 700,
                 'innerkey8': 800,
                 'innerkey9': 900,
                 'innerkey10': 1000,
                 'innerkey11': 1100}
}
```

Attempt:

```
# my thought to change nested dict to nested list
dictToList = [[k, v] for k, v in myDict.items()]

# return result is only changing the outer part 
# of the dict to list but not the inner part
#
[['outerkey1', {'innerkey11': 11, 'innerkey8': 8, 'innerkey4': 4, 'innerkey1': 1, 'innerkey6': 6, 'innerkey7': 7, 'innerkey2': 2, 'innerkey9': 9, 'innerkey5': 5, 'innerkey3': 3, 'innerkey10': 10}], ['outerkey2', {'innerkey11': 1100, 'innerkey8': 800, 'innerkey4': 400, 'innerkey1': 100, 'innerkey6': 600, 'innerkey7': 700, 'innerkey2': 200, 'innerkey9': 900, 'innerkey5': 500, 'innerkey3': 300, 'innerkey10': 1000}]]
```

Example Schema I am trying to Achieve.

```
myDict = [
    [{'outerkey2': [
                    {'innerkey1': 100,
                     'innerkey10': 1000,
                     'innerkey11': 1100,
                     'innerkey2': 200,
                     'innerkey3': 300,
                     'innerkey4': 400,
                     'innerkey5': 500,
                     'innerkey6': 600,
                     'innerkey7': 700,
                     'innerkey8': 800,
                     'innerkey9': 900}
                ]
    }],
    [{'outerkey1': [
                    {'innerkey1': 1,
                     'innerkey10': 10,
                     'innerkey11': 11,
                     'innerkey2': 2,
                     'innerkey3': 3,
                     'innerkey4': 4,
                     'innerkey5': 5,
                     'innerkey6': 6,
                     'innerkey7': 7,
                     'innerkey8': 8,
                     'innerkey9': 9}
                ]
    }]
]
```

Comment: how is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: Thanks let me try to mock something up that would probably better than me trying to explain it.

Comment: That resultant structure looks horrible to work with and doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Thanks I agree, but this is getting converted to Javascript object and the only way to keep the order is to wrap in list.

Comment: How is this being used that makes order  important? Probably a more sensible structure that would work

Comment: This is being used in a Javascript chart so order is important. You don't see that because my dictionary keys and schema are vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired result, you can do something like this:

```
myDict = [[{k : [myDict[k]]}] for k in myDict.keys()]
```

This will give you:

```
[[{'outerkey2': [{'innerkey11': 1100, 'innerkey3': 300, 'innerkey2': 200, 'innerkey6': 600, 'innerkey10': 1000, 'innerkey8': 800, 'innerkey4': 400, 'innerkey5': 500, 'innerkey1': 100, 'innerkey9': 900, 'innerkey7': 700}]}], [{'outerkey1': [{'innerkey11': 11, 'innerkey3': 3, 'innerkey2': 2, 'innerkey6': 6, 'innerkey10': 10, 'innerkey8': 8, 'innerkey4': 4, 'innerkey5': 5, 'innerkey1': 1, 'innerkey9': 9, 'innerkey7': 7}]}]]
```

Comment: This is close and I made another mistake in my schema but how do I wrap the outer part keys in the list. This time I have the complete schema correct in my question.

Comment: @Matt edited my answer. Take a look and tell me if anything's wrong.

Comment: @Matt glad I could help :)